# what is the difference between api and device files in linux?

Tags: linux, io, linux-device-driver

[Difference between an API and a device driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167526/difference-between-an-api-and-a-device-driver)

From the above link i read that API is like a specification that describes what to do, while a driver is an implementation that describes how to do it.

Now, i couldn't find API in linux for display, audio etc.I have also read on internet that linux provides device files to interact with device drivers. we can communicate to devices by writing or reading in those files but as written above API is the specification that describes what to do and API layer is missing here.so, i don't know what commands to writes in those files to interact with devices. ex-rasterize a image on display with the help of these device files.

Comment: Don't get too hung up on the difference between APIs and device drivers or device files. It's like comparing apples and mortgages. As to your practical question, how to show an image on screen: this depends on what technology you want to use. Options in Linux are (at least) using a console framebuffer, or using the X windowing system. For both, libraries exist to get the job done, no need to interact with device files yourself.

Comment: display was only an example what to do for interacting with other devices?do i need to find libraries for each device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device files are just a practical way to communicate between user space and the kernel. Some device files (most notably, block devices) have a uniform API to them, but that's kinda besides the point.

For most standard operations, you would not interact directly with a device file, but instead use a library, exposing a documented API, for doing what you want. So, if you want to play sound files, you'll use, e.g., `libjack`, or even a higher abstraction layer, such as `gstreamer` or `libvlc`.

It is possible, and even likely, that those library use a device file for their actual output. You need not deal with that, unless you want to.

In other cases, you do want to open the device file and interact with it. In those cases, you need to read the relevant documentation to see how to do that. Some device files merely accept `read` and `write` requests. Others, such as `tty` devices, have `ioctl` commands that modify how they work. The man page for the relevant device will tell you what you need to know.

In general, many treat device files as extension of the kernel's API. In fact, many call the `ioctl` command "user defined syscalls". In all cases, just read the documentation to see what you need to do.

Comment: can you please give me the link to these documentations?

Comment: Not without knowing what you're trying to do, no. In general, go to your favorite search engine and type the name of the interface.

Comment: dev/dsp -Digital Signal Processor. Basically this forms the interface between software which produces sound and your soundcard. now where i can find its documentation. I couldn't find on google.

Comment: Search for "linux dsp library"